# Calling function from included file on form submit

Tags: php

I want to call a function from an included file when a form is pressed:

```
<?php include 'app/lc.php'; $lc = new lc();?>
                <form action="<?php $lc->create_user('1', '2'); ?>">
                  Email:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="lastname">
                  <br>
                  Password:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="lastname">
                  <br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

above I try to create an instance of the lc class and then run the create user function in that class.

However, this results in my code breaking at the action tag in the form. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a PHP function from a form's `action` tag. You need to put it in another file and then call it or call that other file using AJAX

E.G.

Form.php

```
<form action="createuser.php" method="post">
 Email:<br>
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <br>
 Password:<br>
 <input type="text" name="password">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="cu" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

CreateUser.php

```
<?php 

include 'app/lc.php';
$lc = new lc();

if(!empty($_POST['submit']){
    $lc->create_user('1', '2');
    // or $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'], etc.
}
```